# Params dont get passed to the object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, creation, mysql2

i'm working on a spanish system for a hospital.
I got a scaffold named persona.

Well in my controller i got a "new" and a "create" method, like almost always.
I can get to the new_persona view (with form) and enter some datas. The problem is now, when i want to create the person i've inserted, i get the following error:

> "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Hds::PersonasController#create"

Furthermore it says me that 2 columns cant be null. Sure, i got the mysql-option that null should be false, because i dont want this 2 columns ever to be empty.
The problem is that rails rises this error even when i inserted something in those fields.
Hope you understand me and can help me. Here the code:

personas_controller new and create:

```
def new
  @persona = Hds::Persona.new



  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @persona }
  end
end


def create
    @persona = Hds::Persona.new(params[:persona])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @persona.save!
        format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @persona, status: :created, location: @persona }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(@persona, :validate=>true) do |f| %>
  <% if @persona.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@persona.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this persona from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @persona.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<table class="form_table">
  <tr class="partial_head">
    <th colspan="2">
      <h3>Datos personales</h3>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
      <div class="field">
        <td><%= f.label :numero_doc %></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :numero_doc %></td>
      </div>
  </tr>


[...]

</table>

 f.submit

<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help!!
Greetings,
CO

Here the full error message:

> Mysql2::Error: Column 'apellido_pat' cannot be null: INSERT INTO
>   `hds_personas` (`apellido_mat`, `apellido_pat`, `centro_trabajo`,
>   `ciudadania`, `ciudadania2_id`, `ciudadania_id`, `conctacto`,
>   `created_at`, `direccion`, `documento_ident_id`, `email`, `estado_cd`,
>   `estado_civil_cd`, `estudio_id`, `fecha_defuncion`,
>   `fecha_nacimiento`, `nombre_comercial`, `nombres`, `nro_hijos`,
>   `numero_doc`, `ocupacion`, `ocupacion_id`, `origen_etnico_cd`,
>   `profesion`, `profesion_id`, `razon_social`, `religion_cd`,
>   `religion_string`, `representante`, `ruc`, `servicio_basico_gral_id`,
>   `sexo_cd`, `telf_contacto`, `telf_fijo`, `telf_movil`,
>   `tipo_documento_cd`, `ubigeo_direccion_id`, `ubigeo_nacimiento_id`,
>   `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   '2013-06-24 07:39:24', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   '2013-06-24 07:39:24')

And here the parameters:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"VYHiP9/zLNjZ0ElAFh1IeC4s5X5oxVFFhpbmbK2oVAs=", 
>   "hds_persona"=>{"numero_doc"=>"",  "sexo"=>"masculino", 
>   "nombres"=>"test",  "apellido_pat"=>"test",  "apellido_mat"=>"", 
>   "direccion"=>"",  "fecha_nacimiento"=>"",  "estado_civil"=>"soltero", 
>   "nro_hijos"=>"",  "telf_movil"=>"",  "email"=>"", 
>   "ubigeo_direccion_id"=>"",  "ubigeo_nacimiento_id"=>"", 
>   "ciudadania_id"=>"",  "ciudadania2_id"=>"", 
>   "origen_etnico"=>"asiatico",  "religion"=>"catolico", 
>   "estudio_id"=>"",  "ocupacion_id"=>"",  "profesion_id"=>""}, 
>   "commit"=>"Create Persona"}

Comment: what is Hds::Persona.new()???? can you try this Persona.new()

Comment: Could you post full errors? And column names?

Comment: Hds::Persona is my class. Hds is the namespace i got in this case. If I try it without the Hds i get "uninitialized constant Hds::PersonasController::Persona". I posted full error above, in my error are the colum names listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it should be

> params[:hds_persona]

in my create-method.

Thank you!